# Is it possible to combine angular monorepo and angular micro-frontend to obtain the advantages of both methods?

Tags: angular, monorepo, micro-frontend

Is it possible to combine angular monorepo and angular micro-frontend to obtain the advantages of both methods?
points:
scalability for large projects without difficult.
code sharing and collaboration.
bundles size.
cost time for building large projects.
Independent development and deployment.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- scalability for large projects : you don't need to make "micro-frontend", you can just make libraries that get imported into your main application, or modules that are lazy loaded
- code sharing and collaboration : not relying on "micro-frontends"
- bundles size : tree shaking is in charge of that, again not related to "micro-frontends" but rahter how you code
- cost time for building large projects : creating multiple apps/libraries is actually achieveing the opposite : building one application is the fastest one
- Independent development and deployment : development is the same as above points, deployments implies that none of your apps/libraries rely on each other, will it be the case ?

To summarize, except for distinct deployments, it does not look like you need "micro-frontends" right ?

Comment: how don't needed "micro-frontend" in case large project, scalability, development with huge team ! i think you may be understood my question not right